# Cannot find module '~/utility/functions' from 'Compnent.vue'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm runing unit test for vue files. in the vue component i have imported `~/utility/functions` file it worked in vue but while testing im getting

**Cannot find module '~/utility/functions' from 'Compnent.vue'** error

jest.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    "js",
    "json",
    "vue"
  ],
  modulePaths: [ "<rootDir>" ],
  moduleDirectories: [
    "node_modules", "<rootDir>"
  ],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.vue$": "@vue/vue2-jest"
  }
};
```